# Do you call this a device diagnostic or device diagnosis?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns, terminology

Let's say a technician is checking what is wrong about an electronic device (for example a smartphone), list the problems, in order to repair it afterwards.

Would you call this process (using a noun) a ***diagnostic*** of the phone, or a ***diagnosis*** of the phone?
Or maybe there is a better word?

Example sentence

> The ??? the technican did on the phone tells us the screen is broken.

I can't fully grasp the difference between diagnosis and diagnostic (the latter is supposed to be an adjective, I'm looking for a noun).

Comment: ***Diagnosis*** is a ***noun***, whereas ***diagnostic*** is normally an ***adjective*** - but the plural noun usage ***diagnostics*** is fairly common (EQV ***diagnostic procedures***), so at least *some* people in the IT world are happy to "back derive" the singular noun from the adjective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks, this is exactly what I figured, without being sure. So using diagnostic as a singular noun isn't really correct, but it would be understandable to a native speaker and make sense ?

Comment: I don't like to bandy around words like "correct" in contexts like this. Obviously there's no problem *understanding* your example. But idiomatically, almost all native speakers would use the plural as indicated above: *The **diagnostics** the technician did on the phone **tell** us the screen is broken.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the comments provide satisfactory answer but are unlikely to be elevated to a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [diagnostic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnostic) (as a noun) is a test.

A [diagnosis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnosis) is a conclusion about identifying a disease or problem from symptoms (what the patient tells you about themselves) and signs (what the physician or diagnostician sees in the patient/problem). Signs include diagnostic tests, or in other words, diagnostics.

For example, chills is a symptom, something the person says they feel, but a high temperature recorded on a thermometer is a sign or diagnostic.

If you're trying to fix an object, the repair person tries to diagnose the problem using (one or more) diagnostics.

So for your sentence the most appropriate word choice would be:

> The diagnostics the technician did on the phone tells us the screen is broken.

Answer (score 4):

**Diagnostics** in the plural is probably the word you want. Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnostic), *diagnostic* means "the art or practice of diagnosis: often used in plural".

A *diagnostic* is a single result, measurement, or metric that is used to help diagnose a problem. The engineer probably does multiple things to diagnose a problem, and the processes or tasks are together called *diagnostics*.

A *diagnosis* in medicine is either the process of finding out what is wrong with a patient, or the statement of what is wrong with the patient (see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnosis)); the word is used outside of medicine, but often with a metaphorical quality analogous to the process of diagnosing a disease in a patient.

Hence the sentence you want is: *The diagnostics the technician did on the phone tell us the screen is broken.*

Comment: "Diagnostic" as a noun isn't really a thing except in cases of elision.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "diagnostics" for an electronic device commonly refers to a set of software test procedures. [Google "run diagnostics"](https://www.google.com/search?q=run%20diagnostics) for many examples. With the electronic device completely powered off, of course one can can still diagnose issues to create a diagnostic report with the diagnosis.

So for your sentence, both word choices are appropriate but have slightly different meanings.

> The ??? the technican did on the phone tells us the screen is broken.

Using "diagnosis" means the technician conducted standard troubleshooting processes to find the issue, whether software tests, past experience, visual inspection, or otherwise.

Using "diagnostic" means the technician ran a software test procedure. Singular is fine, but I think plural "diagnostics" is more common, since the software procedure is typically composed of multiple separate tests and provides multiple different reports.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosis is used when you want to find out what is wrong with a person, whereas diagnostic is used when you want to problem solve (like with a phone).

Also, adjectives can end in -ic and also be nouns. Psychic, for instance, or academic.

Comment: No, this is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Both are grammatically correct and both would be understood by many English speakers. Many technical people may prefer "diagnostic" when dealing with equipment.